# Event bus with configurable encapsulation and permission levels (subscribe-only/emit+subscribe)

Tags: events, event-handling, encapsulation

Suppose we have a `CompanyService` which is our (singleton) event bus used for communication between classes.

```java
class CompanyService {
  EventEmitter<Schedule> workScheduleChanged;
  // (plus many others)
}
```

We also have the classes `Manager` and `Employee` that have this `CompanyService` injected.

```java
class Manager {
  @Injected
  CompanyService companyService;

  void changeWorkSchedule(Schedule newSchedule) {
    this.companyService.workScheduleChanged.emit(newSchedule);
  }
}
```

```java
class Employee {
  @Injected
  CompanyService companyService;

  Schedule workSchedule;

  void setup() {
    this.workScheduleChanged.subscribe(newSchedule -> this.workSchedule = newSchedule);
  }

  void illegallyChangeWorkSchedule(Schedule newSchedule) {
    this.companyService.workScheduleChanged.emit(newSchedule);
  }
}
```

I'd like to prevent classes like `Employee` from directly calling `emit` on events inside `CompanyService`. But I would still like for them to be able to `subscribe` to said events.

I wish to somehow inject a subscribe-only version of the `CompanyService` class. The constraints are:

1. No repetition
2. No bypassing this encapsulation in an underhanded manner
3. Type safety

The simplest solution is creating another class that wraps `CompanyService`'s fields in a way that prevents access to their `emit` method:

```java
class CompanyServiceSubscribeOnly {
  @Injected
  CompanyService companyService;

  EventSubscriber<Schedule> getWorkScheduleChanged() {
    return companyService.workScheduleChanged.asEventSubscriber();
  }

  // (plus many others)
}
```

(In this context, `EventSubscriber` can only subscribe to events, not emit them also)

This solution breaks constraint #1, as I need to create a wrapper method for each emitter of `CompanyService`.

Another solution would be to wrap the fields selectively, like so:

```java
class CompanyServiceSubscribeOnly {
  @Injected
  CompanyService companyService;

  EventSubscriber<T> getAsEventSubscriber<T>((CompanyService -> EventEmitter<T>) selector) {
    return selector(companyService).asEventSubscriber();
  }
}
```

But instead of calling it normally like so:

```java
companyServiceSubscribeOnly.getAsEventSubscriber(companyService -> companyService.workScheduleChanged).subscribe(...)
```

...nothing would prevent me from underhandedly calling `emit`:

```java
companyServiceSubscribeOnly.getAsEventSubscriber(companyService -> companyService.emit(...
```

...which breaks constraint #2.

A last solution that I thought about involves creating just one event emitter where events are distinguished by the name under which they emit, and their names would be kept in an enum. While this complies with the first 2 constraints, it would make my events *typeless* i.e., there is no way of knowing at compile-time that my event called `"work-schedule-changed"` returns a `Schedule`, which breaks constraint #3.

I tried to make the examples language-agnostic as I initially bumped my head on this problem in Angular and didn't want to mess up the examples with framework-specific clutter.

I would like a solution that checks all 3 constrains in any statically-typed language or even pseudocode.